# GL_SHORT as texture coordinates

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, textures

Instruments encourages me to use GL_SHORTs for texture coordinates. I do that for quads where I only need values 0 and 1.

Can I also use GL_SHORT for other cases where I need values between 0 and 1 if the precision of a short is enough? If so how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get max precision, you can use values 0..32767 for specifying texture coordinates as GL_SHORT to specify values from 0.0f to 1.0f. Then you will get precision 1/32767, which approximately is 0.00003. Is it enough for you? - that is up to you and your application. Most likely it will be enough for you.

To specify some value between 0 and 1, then either use texture matrix with scaling (if you are on GLES1) or just multiply texture coordinate with proper scaling uniform in your fragment shader (if you are on GLES2).

Here's a simple example for GLES1 - lets say your texture ir 100x200 and you don't need to specify texture coordinates with less precision that 1 texel. Then you can set your texture matrix to scale for following factors - 1/100 and 1/200:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glPushMatrix();
glLoadIdentity();
glScalex(65536/100, 65536/200, 1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
```

After that in your vertex array/buffer you can use:

- (0, 0) to specify value of (0.0f, 0.0f)
- (10, 40) to specify value (10/100.0f, 40/200.0f) = (0.1f, 0.2f)
- (100, 200) to specify value of (1.0f, 1.0f).